# Can we use customHooks into redux Saga function

Tags: react-hooks, redux-saga, react-state, reselect, use-reducer

Following custom hooks as state selector and using that within "functional View" component.
Now, I need to use that in redux Saga function.  Can we use that into Saga function or I have to use some other approach instead of using custom hooks into Saga function ?

```
export function useSelectAllEntries()
{
return useSelector(
({allEntries=[]}) =>[...allEntries],shallowEqual
);
}

export function useSelectFilteredByMakeEntries()
{
const selectAll = useSelectAllEntries();
return selectAll.filter(...);
}

export function useSelectFilteredByCreatorEntries()
{
const selectAll = useSelectAllEntries();
return selectAll.filter(...);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of defining these as custom hooks, define them as selectors instead. Redux selectors may be freely shared between multiple different use-cases.

```js
export const allEntriesSelector = ({ allEntries = [] }) => allEntries;

export const allEntriesFilteredByMakeEntriesSelector = state =>
  allEntriesSelector(state).filter(...);

export const allEntriesFilteredByCreatorEntriesSelector = state =>
  allEntriesSelector(state).filter(...);
```

Then, when you want to use them in a function component, just call `useSelector`:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const entries = useSelector(allEntriesSelector);
  const filteredByMake = useSelector(allEntriesFilteredByMakeEntriesSelector);
  const filteredByCreator = useSelector(allEntriesFilteredByCreatorEntriesSelector);

  return (...);
}
```

and when you want to use them within a saga:

```js
import { select } from 'redux-saga/effects';

function* mySaga() {
  const entries = yield select(allEntriesSelector);
  const filteredByMake = yield select(allEntriesFilteredByMakeEntriesSelector);
  const filteredByCreator = yield select(allEntriesFilteredByCreatorEntriesSelector);
}
```

Comment: actually, using custom selector with shallowEqual to achieve memoization. It would loose if I use direct selector.

Comment: You can memoize your selector then, instead of passing an equality function to `useSelector`. Check out the docs for [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#creating-a-memoized-selector).

Comment: So, just for curiosity, when to write customHook to select state and when to use selector ?

Comment: tl;dr: always use a selector (when it's possible to do so) - you should only reach for a custom hook when you're performing React-specific logic, such as modifying component state or running side effects. Since you're using Redux (state) and Saga (side effects), you'll often be able to accomplish what you'd traditionally need a custom hook for within Redux/Saga itself.